# Deployment Compound Projects using Utility Module With Hibernate 5 and Spring 4 in Eclipse on Tomcat failed

Tags: spring, eclipse, hibernate, maven, tomcat

I decided to split the work to more modules in Eclipse Mars (Neon). One module is deployable as war REST Service. Using integrated Tomcat (version 8.0.41) to use: *Right click on Server in Servers View -> Add and Remove* causes:

```
    15:42:21.104 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
    15:42:21.123 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.c.s.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Jun 29 15:42:21 CEST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
    15:42:21.201 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.c.s.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Registering annotated classes: [class com.deepam.spring.config.AppRestConfig]
    15:42:21.218 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
    java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:724)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:531)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:355)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:286)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:120)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:72)
        at java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Class.java:3521)
        at java.lang.Class.annotationData(Class.java:3510)
        at java.lang.Class.getAnnotations(Class.java:3446)
        at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.<init>(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:68)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AnnotatedGenericBeanDefinition.<init>(AnnotatedGenericBeanDefinition.java:56)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.registerBean(AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java:167)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.registerBean(AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java:142)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.register(AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java:131)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.java:210)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:614)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:515)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4851)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Jun 29, 2017 3:42:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
    SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:724)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:531)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:355)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:286)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:120)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:72)
        at java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Class.java:3521)
        at java.lang.Class.annotationData(Class.java:3510)
        at java.lang.Class.getAnnotations(Class.java:3446)
        at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.<init>(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:68)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AnnotatedGenericBeanDefinition.<init>(AnnotatedGenericBeanDefinition.java:56)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.registerBean(AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java:167)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.registerBean(AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java:142)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.register(AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java:131)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.java:210)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:614)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:515)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4851)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

    Jun 29, 2017 3:42:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
    SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
    Jun 29, 2017 3:42:21 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
    INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [201] milliseconds.
    Jun 29, 2017 3:42:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
    SEVERE: Context [/SpringOracleJDBCJPAREST] startup failed due to previous errors
    Jun 29, 2017 3:42:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
    Jun 29, 2017 3:42:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
    SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:170)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1030)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1006)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:958)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:583)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4898)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5537)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:221)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:149)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

If I the same .war file generated from Eclipse this way: *Right click on Parent project -> Run as - Maven Install* put into *{Apache Tomcat Innstallation}/webaaps* directory manually, it woks fine without errors. How can I setup Eclipse to enable automatic deployment without **Context initialization failed** errors?
P.S. One big project merged all together has no problem with deployment. It works fine as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to undeploy .war file from Tomcat integrated environment and copy it straightforwardly into *$tomcat_home/webapps* deployment directory. Every setting can be as they previously were set. It means, Tomcat can be administrated from Eclipse as well. We can restart Tomcat from Eclipse, look on log using Console View etc.
I suppose, that Context needs some further configuration or it is a bug, but this workaround works fine.
There is only one limitation, that automatic deployment is not possible and Tomcat doesn't display deployed modules in View Servers.

[image]

[image]